# Creating SOAP message body

Tags: c#, soap

I would like to know how to create SOAP message, body, and envelope in C#. Any help or links appreciated.

I need to send a SOAP attachment to a third party Web Service. I don't need WCF. I know how it works. My client needs SOAP with attachment.

Comment: Learn WCF - http://msdn.microsoft.com/WCF

Comment: Are you trying to consume an existing web service or write your own?

Comment: i am consuming an existing webservice.so i need to develop a soap message

Comment: Again: **learn WCF!** It's really quite easy to create a client for an existing service. You will get a nice, clean client-side proxy - and you don't need to worry about all the details of handling and constructing SOAP messages - WCF will do that for you. You just create a proxy and call methods - that's all

Comment: Watch this 10 minute screencast: [Creating your first WCF client](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/Endpoint-Screencasts-Creating-Your-First-WCF-Client/)

Comment: i need to send a soap attachment to a third party webservice.since asp.net does not support that i have to build that.ie why i am posting this.fyi i know wcf. but this third party is using normal web service.

Comment: WCF **IS** normal web service - there's absolutely nothing **abnormal** about WCF. If you create a client using my short "how-to" post - what do you get? Can you call that service and pass the attachments along??

Comment: Have to agree with @marc_s above: learn WCF. You do *not* need to create a soap message by hand. See the following for sending attachments through WCF http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2007/08/29/sending-attachments-with-wcf.aspx

Comment: @marc_s: Are you totally oblivious to the fact that WCF does not have out-of-the-box support for SWA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link out http://www.xefteri.com/articles/show.cfm?id=15
It describes process for VS.NET, but in VS2010 it is same process. This was an easiest way.

However, if you can construct SOAP message (for example, if you read WSDL and can construct message without any issues or you used something like SOAP UI (http://www.soapui.org/) to generate few mock up messages and got an idea) then you can simply do POST to that URL like in this example http://www.808.dk/?code-csharp-httpwebrequest

Answer (score 12):

Here's a **really super-short** intro how to do this:

1) Create a new project (any kind - console app, windows app, web app - whatever) - `File > New > Project`

2) In your Solution Explorer, right-click on `References` and choose `Add Service Reference`

[image]

3) In the dialog box that pops up, you need to enter two things:

1. your URL where the service lives (typically with a `?wsdl` query string to grab the WSDL - the service description)
2. your namespace where the service classes will live - pick whatever suits you

[image]

Then click on `Go` - this will talk to that service and see what it has to offer

4) Now, that dialog box should update, and show you the service and its operations, as discovered by Visual Studio:

[image]

5) Click on `OK` and some code gets generated in the background

6) Now instantiate a client-side proxy in your code, and call a method on it:

[image]

That's **all** you have to do - everything else, all the messy details of creating a SOAP header and message body, can be happily left to the WCF runtime.

Now **go learn WCF!**

Comment: +.5 for the nice screenshots, +.5 for dark color scheme :)

Comment: @juliet: Thanks! It's the [Cobalt VS scheme](http://studiostyl.es/schemes/cobalt) - I do like it!

Answer (score 2):

marc_s: learn SOAP with Attachments before recommending others to learn WCF. SwA is not supported by .Net so he's got to roll his own and that is the background for his question.

Comment: Good point you make, but it should be a comment not an answer.